# Detailed error message on TypeError in Chrome and Firefox (what is accessed AND on which reference)

Tags: javascript, firefox, null, typeerror, chromium

I noticed that Chrome and Firefox give different error messages when accessing a variable on an undefined / null reference.

```
let a = {b: {c: null}};
a.b.c.d;
```

Error message in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of null`
Error message in Firefox: `Uncaught TypeError: a.b.c is null`

So Firefox is telling me the Expression for the reference that is null, but not what I am trying to access on it.
In contrast, Chrome is telling me what I am trying to access and that the reference used is null, but not the Expression for the reference.

I would consider both valuable information when debugging. Especially when JS code is minified and line numbers are not matching the development code anymore.

Is it possible to get both information from the browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Firefox Nightly and maybe Firefox Developer Edition you will get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "d", a.b.c is null

This is only happens in these versions of Firefox because trying to change the error message broke websites. [Bug 1259822](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259822)